# Zina during Ramadan

Tags: sin, ramadan, tawba, zina, adultery

Assalamu Alaikum. I commited oral sex zina with the same sex while fasting during Ramadan. But there was no ejaculation or penetration of any sorts.I left it mid way and repented immediately. Pls tell me how to repent for this. Do I have to pay the Kaffarah?? Plss help me out

Answer (score 0):

In Islam, zina and homosexuality is a major sin, and repentance from it requires sincerity of intention and determination not to return to sin.

Repentance must be sincere for the sake of Allah s.w.t., with strong remorse for the sin you have committed, and a sincere determination not to return to it again.

You must ask for forgiveness a lot and pray that Allah will forgive you and accept your repentance. Allah is Forgiving and Merciful and accepts repentance from His servants.

Yes you need to pay the kaffarah because you broke the fast willingly. I think it's fasting for 60 days or choose to feed people for 60 days. I would recommend you to seek out a mufti or a scholar who can help you.

May Allah guide us all to His straight path. Ameen!